# Waitfor in Telnet Perl

Tags: perl, telnet

I don't understand what exactly $telnet_obj->waitfor works. Does it check that all conditions are meet or any one condition? Can anyone explain me please? I've tried to search, but didn't find any satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1):

The examples at the bottom of the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aTelnet) clearly show it being used for alternatives (which makes more sense than matching multiple patterns).

In general, if the documentation doesn't say, it's always worth downloading the package as a tar.gz and having a quick look through the tests in the `t` directory. The tests should show you how it's intended to be used.

Failing that, there's always the "Source" link too.